# Very Tricky Rails Validation Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am having a very tricky problem here with validation. So basically, I have a join model screen_weights with an extra attribute called "weight". The join model is for two models:score and screen.

**Screen has_many :scores through=>:screen_weights**

**Score has_many :screens through=>:screen_weights**

and then my scores are weighed depending on the weight.

let's say I have

**screen_id=1,score_id=1,weight=0.3;**

**screen_id=1,score_id=2,weight=0.7.**

In this way, I will have something as screen 1 which has two scores (1 and 2) with weights 0.3 and 0.7 respectively. The validation needs to be done is sum to 1. 
I will need to check for a particular screen if the weights for the scores add up to 1. How would I achieve this? SELECT SUM(weight) FROM screen_weights GROUP BY screen_id can give me this information. But how can I write a validation for it?
Thanks a lot

Comment: partial class definitions would help here.

Comment: also formatting this question a little wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Screen
  has_many :screen_weights
  validate :weights_sum_to_1

  def weights_sum_to_1
    errors.add_to_base("Weights must add up to 1") unless screen_weights.sum(:weight) == 1
  end
end
```

I think this is what you're going for, though from your explanation of the problem its hard to tell exactly what the classes are doing.

Comment: Karmajunkie, Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad formatting of my question. You solution is what I tried at the beginning. But it won't work because at the point when screen is calling the validation method, the screen have not been saved yet. So screen_weights always return an empty array. This validation will always fail. I don't know how to work around this. Because this validation involves multiple rows in screen_weights table before its parent rows even get saved!